# Database Table Synonym/Alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

So here's the scenario: I have a set of tables named `job_listings_yyyyMMdd`.  Every day, a new table, using the aforementioned naming convention is created and populated with that day's job listings.

When that table is populated, a process is kicked off that transforms the data in the table so that a front-end app can use it.

So, as time goes on, I have a set of tables, something like

`job_listings_20151226`,
`job_listings_20151227`,
`job_listings_20151228`,
...

They all have the exact same table structure, but each table contains only that day's job listings.

What I'd like to do is reference a table, from the service that provides the front-end with this data, named `job_listings`.  Ideally, my daily process would create the new day's table, and after all processing is done and that day's data is ready to be served, then have the process change the synonym/alias (i.e., `job_listings`) to point to the newly populated and processed table for that day.

The idea is that there is not any seam in between data refreshes.  Oracle used to have a concept called Synonyms, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different database systems have different methods for federation and aliasing.  But I think what you want is something that is available in any SQL system -- a view.

```
CREATE VIEW MOST_RECENT_JOB_LISTINGS AS 
SELECT * FROM job_listings_20151228
```

Just change this view's definition every day after the new table is created.

Comment: aye yai yai, so simple.  sometimes, i over-complicate things.  thank you!